# How can I use a variable outside a function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return, using .index method, the position of the picture I am clicking on and then use that number in another variable that has to be external to the function.

```
var index;
    $('.product img').click(function () {
        index = $( ".product img" ).index( this );  //it returns an integer, as expected             
        })

var  myProduct = 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php'; // it returns productNaN.php
```

Only that, although the index method works properly, in my second variable I get instead of an integer NaN.

Comment: Callbacks or global variables :)

Comment: put 'myProduct inside click function'

Comment: Please be more explicit

Comment: The index will only be set after someone fired the 'click' event on that element. `myProduct` will get set immediately after assigning that event-handler and no event could have been fired. So index is still undefined.

Comment: Inside the click event, after you set the `index` set your product url `myProduct`, than do with it whatever you need to do.

Comment: I need to call the variable from outside the function

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: The index gets new value only **after** click event occured, untill than its value is not defined. So, what you do with product URL place inside the function, for example: `function doProduct( index ){ var  myProduct = 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php'; }` and call the function from within click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the order in which that code runs:

1. The variables `index` and `myProduct` are created and given the initial value `undefined`.
2. `$('.product img')` is used to look up elements and then `click` is used to assign an event handler to them.
3. `'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php'` is assigned to `myProduct`; note that `index` is still `undefined`. Since you use it in a math expression (`(index + 1)`), it's coerced to a number, which is `NaN` because `undefined` has no numeric equivalent. So the overall result is what you see.
4. Possibly, at some point in the future, someone clicks one of those elements, at which time `index` is set to a new value. This has no effect on `myProduct`.

You may want to move the assignment of `myProduct` *inside* the `click` handler, in which case you probably don't need `index` outside the handler at all:

```
var myProduct;
$('.product img').click(function () {
    var index = $( ".product img" ).index( this );
    myProduct = 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php';
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Is there a way to load or redirect to the page 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php' at the same time?

Comment: @SerbanMorcan: Sure: `location = 'product' + (index + 1) + '.php';` But I wouldn't do that. Instead, when generating the `img` elements, I'd put them in anchors with that as the `href` of the anchor, so the user gets all the benefits of proper links (shift+click, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This code will only evaluated when click, and your next line

```
var  myProduct = 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php';
```

will be evaluted at the beginning and for only 1 time not each time click, and for sure index it undefined at this time,

and when click callback called the code inside only which will be evaluated and the next line not if you want to evaluate it then put it inside:

```
 var index; 
 var myProduct;  
 $('.product img').click(function () {
    index = $( ".product img" ).index( this );  
    myProduct = 'product'+ (index + 1)+'.php';
 })
```